# Validate Date in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have this booking table

> start_date | end_date

```
2020-12-15   2020-12-18
2020-12-19   2020-12-22
```

In this table booking data is getting saved, but i want to validate date before saving data, if start date and end date is between the database date then that record should not get saved.

I'm using this query :

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->start_date));
$end_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+17 hours', strtotime($request->start_date)));

    $bookingData =Booking::whereBetween('start_date', [
        $start_date, $end_date
    ])->whereBetween('end_date', [
        $start_date, $end_date
    ])->exists();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$exists = Booking::whereBetween('start_date', [
    $request->start_date, $request->end
])->whereBetween('end_date', [
    $request->start_date, $request->end
])->exists();
```

Comment: Thanks, But i want to match it with database values, start_date and end_date entered by user should not already exist in database

Comment: So you save the rows to the database first and then validate for some reason?

Comment: yes user has already booked if any user wants to book if it is between the range that  is already booked then user cannot book it

Comment: Sorry I understand now, then you can simply use `whereBetween` with your dates and `->exists()` to check the existence.

Comment: Should i pass field name also with request? I have two fields i.e. start_date and end_date in my database

Comment: So any of start_date and end_date is between the given start and end dates you should get `$exists = true`

Comment: Thanks it is working with orWhereBetween in the second part of the query

Answer (score 0):

**if any booking scheduled already booked given date range you can check using the below code**

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM booking ". " WHERE (('$request->start_date'  BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)". " OR ('$request->end_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)". " OR (start_date BETWEEN '$request->start_date' AND '$request->end_date'))");
```